# Error with classes and vector : SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am doing a small game , and right now I am trying to code the Characer movements , so here is the code which does the error :

When I call `charac.move(DOWN,terrain);` , which code is

```
void Character::move(direction d,Terrain& terrain){
    if(d==UP && !terrain.isTileWall(playerCoords.x,playerCoords.y+1)){
        playerCoords.y++;
    }
    if(d==DOWN && !terrain.isTileWall(playerCoords.x,playerCoords.y-1)){ //Here is the error at terrain.isTileWall()
        playerCoords.y--;
    }
    if(d==RIGHT && !terrain.isTileWall(playerCoords.x+1,playerCoords.y)){
        playerCoords.x++;
    }   
    if(d==LEFT && !terrain.isTileWall(playerCoords.x-1,playerCoords.y)){
        playerCoords.x--;
    }
    terrain.setCharacter(this,playerCoords.x,playerCoords.y); //In case this could be a problem Character is a pointer in Terrain code
}
```

And `isTileWall()` is :

```
bool Terrain::isTileWall(int x,int y){
    return terrain[x][y].isWall(); //Error is in the [x][y] I think
}
```

terrain is an Instance of the Terrain class
In this class the terrain is a double-dimenshioned vector who is declared by `terrain = std::vector<std::vector<Tile> >(xSize,std::vector<Tile>(ySize))`

`isWall` is just a `return bool wall`

The error leads to this part of the vector header :

```
  //stl_vector.h

  // element access
  /**
   *  @brief  Subscript access to the data contained in the %vector.
   *  @param __n The index of the element for which data should be
   *  accessed.
   *  @return  Read/write reference to data.
   *
   *  This operator allows for easy, array-style, data access.
   *  Note that data access with this operator is unchecked and
   *  out_of_range lookups are not defined. (For checked lookups
   *  see at().)
   */
  reference
  operator[](size_type __n) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
```

I really dont understand what is the problem here , so if anyone understands it I would be so pleased.

The error occurs for any value of x and y

I have lots of code in my program so if you want any more of it , just ask

Comment: What is `terrain`? What are the values of `x` and `y` when the crash happens?

Comment: Yes I forgot to put the declatation of it , I'll add it now

Comment: Just guessing here, but what if `playerCoords.y` is zero? Then you will use a negative index accessing the vector and you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should check the coordinates before using them as indexes.

Comment: I am aware of the problem , I just thinked about it yesterday and was going to fix this , but like I said it happens for all x and y